# select what element of collection is not in a column of table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to set up a sql query where I have a bunch of varchar values that correspond to a column of a specific database table. The result should give me all values that are *not* in the table column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT x.a 
FROM  ( SELECT ('1','2','3') AS a ) x 
WHERE  x not in  ( 
                    SELECT knr 
                    FROM table 
                 )
```

I didn't get this to work because the inner select is treated as a single record I don't know how to set it up right, or if this is even possible.

Can anyone give me a hint how to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.a 
FROM
    ( SELECT '1' AS a 
    UNION ALL
      SELECT '2'
    UNION ALL 
      SELECT '3'
    ) x 
WHERE a NOT IN
      ( SELECT knr FROM table1 )
```

Postgres has implemented the [Table Values Constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html) syntax, so you can use this, too:

```
SELECT x.a 
FROM
    ( VALUES 
        ('1'), 
        ('2'),
        ('3')
    ) AS x(a) 
WHERE a NOT IN
      ( SELECT knr FROM table1 )
```

Comment: The `VALUES` clause has been working in PostgreSQL as long as I can remember. I recently used it in version 8.4, but probably long before that.

Comment: @Erwin: Thnx, I'll correct that. I thought it had too, but the time I posted a fast search on *"Postgres Table Values Constructor"* gave me no results.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the second query works perfectly for my needs. The first is more general because it works for mysql and mssql too if you replace x with x.a in the where clause.

Comment: @acoder: Oops, yes, the `x` should be `x.a` or just `a` in both versions. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select X.A
from 
    (select '1' as A union select '2' as A union select '3' as A)  x 

where A not in (select knr from table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function [**`regexp_split_to_table()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to shorten your syntax:

```
SELECT x
FROM   regexp_split_to_table('1~2~3', '~') AS x
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.knr = x
WHERE  t.knr IS NULL
```

Use a string as delimiter that is guaranteed not to be part of any value.
This only works if `tbl.knr` is actually a **string type** like `text`.

If it is, in fact, a **numeric type** like `integer` do instead:

```
SELECT x
FROM   regexp_split_to_table('1~2~3', '~') AS x
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.knr = x::int
WHERE  t.knr IS NULL
```

---

Or, for `text`:

```
SELECT x
FROM   regexp_split_to_table('1~2~3', '~') AS x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl t WHERE t.knr = x)
```

For `integer`:

```
SELECT x
FROM   regexp_split_to_table('1~2~3', '~') AS x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl t WHERE t.knr = x::int)
```